# Bash: echo inside a conditional statement doesn't print anything

Tags: bash

i'm trying to modify a bash script that i saw on a book i'm reading. the original working script is this:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
    echo "Usage: ./pingscript.sh [network]"
    echo "Example: ./pingscript.sh 192.168.1"
else
    for x in $(seq 70 80); do

    ping -c 1 $1.$x | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | sed 's/.$//'
    
    done
fi
```

I tried to modify it to print something if the IP is not reachable, I made some try but it never worked. this is the last code I've tried. it prints just the first IP and then nothing, only blank lines until the for cycle ends.

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "$1" == "" ]
then
    echo "Usage: ./pingscript.sh [network]"
    echo "Example: ./pingscript.sh 192.168.1"
else

    for x in $(seq 70 80); do
        str=$(ping -c 1 $1.$x | grep "64 bytes" | cut -d " " -f 4 | sed 's/.$//')
        echo "$str"
        if [[ $str == *"Unreachable"* ]]
        then
            echo "$1.$x is unreachable"
        fi
    done
fi
```

what am i doing wrong?

Comment: I guess the "Unreachable" goes to stderr, not stdout, so it's not captured by the command substitution `$(...)`. You can redirect stderr to stdout to capture it.

Comment: If the host is unreachable, the exit status of `ping` will be non-zero. Test that instead of any output to either standard output or standard error. `if ! ping ...; then echo "..."`.

Comment: Unrelated: you can use `{70..80}` instead of `$(seq 70 80)`. It produces the same result but it is faster. Read about [brace expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Brace-Expansion) in the Bash documentation.

Comment: Unrelated, `ping -c 1 "$1.$x" | awk -F'[ :]+' '/64 bytes/{print $4}' `

Comment: @Jetchisel i don't understand awk, i never used it. i have to read the manual page, but thank you.

Comment: @chepner until now i never studied about standard output, error etc. i guess i have to go further, but it's hard to find high quality beginner friendly resources about bash

Comment: @choroba how can i send it to the stderr?

Comment: `bash -x yourscript`, to run your script with debug logging, is always a good place to start. (Well, that, and https://shellcheck.net/)

Comment: BTW, `seq` is best avoided. It's not part of bash itself, and it's also not standardized, so OS vendors aren't obligated to provide it, or to make sure it behaves any particular way when they _do_ provide it; and, as an external command, starting it up involves `fork()`/`execve()` performance overhead. Consider `for ((x=70; x<=80; x++)); do`, which is guaranteed to work anywhere your shell is bash; and unlike `for x in {70..80}`, it works even when your start and end points are variables (cc @axiac)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I'm really confused with Bash honestly, I can't find a beginner friendly book or course, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: The [BashGuide](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide) is a good resource -- it was assembled by the #bash IRC channel as an alternative to some less-accurate resources that had a lot of Google juice (particularly, it was built to be a higher-quality replacement for TLDP's "Advanced" Bash Scripting guide, which is unfortunately still around, and still full of bad examples).  There are also a lot of great links in https://stackoverflow.com/tags/bash/info. The same wiki also has the [BashFAQ](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ) and [BashPitfalls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank you, i'll study on that guide hoping that it's good as you said

Answer (score 0):

When I ping something that is not there, I do not always get an `Unreachable` in the output. For example:

```
$ ping -c1 10.1.1.1
PING 10.1.1.1 (10.1.1.1) 56(84) bytes of data.

--- 10.1.1.1 ping statistics ---
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

But actually, you don't care what is the output of `ping`; you want to know if the hosts are reachable. So,

```
if ping -c 1 $1.$x ; then
    echo "$1.$x is Reachable"
else
    echo "$1.$x is unreachable"
fi
```

will do the trick.

Or,

```
if ! ping -c 1 $1.$x > /dev/null ; then
    echo "$1.$x is unreachable"
fi
```

The `> /dev/null` will throw away all output. You could also `ping -c 1 $1.$x | grep 'packet loss'`, which will give you some output.

Comment: Thank you, in the second example i don't see the IP if they are reachable tho, since the output is redirected to /dev/null, am i right? and another thing, a user above wrote this: ping -c 1 "$1.$x" | awk -F'[ :]+' '/64 bytes/{print $4}' 
i've searched about awk, but i haven't found similar example. can you explain to me what is '[ :]+' and '/64 bytes'?

Comment: There is a good awk tutorial at https://grymoire.com/Unix/Awk.html . Read about the Field Seperator (`-F`) and `awk`'s `/pattern/{action}` processing. Good luck.

Comment: Your idea about `/dev/null` is correct; see addition in the answer.